# Assist me with Displaying Post Data in Schema Markup in Wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, web-deployment, jsonschema

I am going to assign Custom Fields to Schema Markup, But it didn't display the value. Your help regarding the issue will be appreciated.

Note: The custom file is displaying data outer than Schema JSON code. I Just want to display the data within the schema markup. Thank you

**Code Example**

```
<?php 

$hiring_organization = get_field('hiring_organization');
$organization_url = get_field('organization_url');
$online_apply = get_field('online_apply'); 
$form = get_field('form'); 
$industry_type = get_field('industry_type'); 
$employment_type = get_field('employment_type'); 
$job_published_date = get_field('job_published_date'); 
$job_expiry_date = get_field('job_expiry_date'); 
$job_location = get_field('job_location'); 
$address = get_field('address'); 
$postal_code = get_field('postal_code'); 
$min_salary = get_field('min_salary'); 
$max_salary = get_field('max_salary'); 
$responsibilities = get_field('responsibilities'); 
$skills = get_field('skills'); 
$qualification = get_field('qualification'); 
$experience = get_field('experience'); 
$salary_base = get_field('salary_base'); 

?>



<!-- START SCHEMA -->
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "https://schema.org/",
  "@type": "JobPosting",
  "title": "<?php the_title(); ?>",
  "description": "<?php the_content(); ?>",
  "hiringOrganization" : {
    "@type": "Organization",
    "name": "<?php $hiring_organization; ?>",
    "sameAs": "<?php $organization_url; ?>"
  },
  "industry": "<?php $industry_type; ?>",
  "employmentType": "<?php $employment_type; ?>",
  "datePosted": "<?php $job_published_date; ?>",
  "validThrough": "<?php $job_expiry_date; ?>",
  "jobLocation": {
    "@type": "Place",
    "address": {
      "@type": "PostalAddress",
      "streetAddress": "<?php $address; ?>",
      "addressLocality": "<?php $job_location; ?>",
      "postalCode": "<?php $postal_code; ?>",
      "addressCountry": "PK"
    }
  },
  "baseSalary": {
    "@type": "MonetaryAmount",
    "currency": "PKR",
    "value": {
      "@type": "QuantitativeValue",
      "minValue": <?php $min_salary; ?>,
      "maxValue": <?php $max_salary; ?>,
      "unitText": "<?php $salary_base; ?>"
    }
  },
  "responsibilities": "<?php $responsibilities; ?>",
  "skills": "<?php $skills; ?>",
  "qualifications": "<?php $qualification; ?>",
  "educationRequirements": "<?php $qualification; ?>",
  "experienceRequirements": "<?php $experience; ?>"
}
</script>
<!-- END SCHEMA -->
```

Please Remember that the_title(); and the_content(); is displaying data. Only the custom filled data is not displaying. Thanks

Comment: You have to echo your variables

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
I Forget echo before the variable. the php code just need echo before the variable like.
`"name": "<?php echo $hiring_organization; ?>"` instead of  `"name": "<?php $hiring_organization; ?>"`